# How to create two-way directive for AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

First week with AngularJS, I used the code for file uploading directive from https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

It works great when reading the content -- user selects the file, I read it in JS, and then after sending it to server I would like to clear it (by setting `null`). And here is the problem -- it does not work, the file name in `<input>` is not changed.

How should I modify it get two-way directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angularjs doesn't seem to have support for two-way binding for an input element with type 'file'. Refer [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375).

A simple way to achieve what you are looking for could be through resetting the input value after the file upload is done. Set an id, say 'fileInput' for the input field, and then use:

```
document.getElementById("fileInput").value = "";
```

to reset the input value to blank.

Here's the [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aditiraveesh/ZG9re/5547/) for the same.

Comment: Thank you, pity there is no such binding though.